# html pages loading is time very different

Tags: html

Is there a specific reason why two HTML pages have a different loading time? 
(They are in the same local folder)
When I test them on a browser, one of them is extremely slower than the other.

Any help? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that can lead to different page load times for two pages on the same server. The folder they are in is not one of them.

Common reasons include:

- **Number and size of images on the page:** Large images (or more images) will take longer to load. Note that changing the display size in HTML/CSS doesn't change the file size/load time. It only changes how it is displayed on a screen.
- **Scripts:** If you are querying/importing from a database, performing JavaScript functions, etc. Those all take time. The more you have/less efficient they are, the longer the load time.
- **External Resources:** If you are utilizing large external resources (APIs, JS libraries, etc) on the page, it'll increase load time.